# Shopify adding the product price inside the add to cart button

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I want to add the price within the button "add to cart".

As you can see I am able to add the price within the button but when i change the variant it disappears. (the URL changes along with selecting a different varient)

[GIF that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYtBm.gif)

Any suggestions?

The current code is:

```html
<button
      {% if product.empty? %}type="button"{% else %}type="submit"{% endif %}
      name="add"
      id="AddToCart-{{ section_id }}"
      class="btn btn--full add-to-cart{% if enable_dynamic_buttons %} btn--secondary{% endif %}"
      {% unless current_variant.available %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}>
      <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section_id }}"  data-default-text="{{ default_text }}">
        {{ button_text }} {{ current_variant.price | money }}
      </span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use Javascript. When you render your page for the first time, Liquid rendering places a price on the button. But when you change a variant, no Liquid is rendering, so you're left with using Javascript. I am sure that by now, after 10+ years you can find some examples out there that do what you need done.

When a variant changes, usually some Javascript runs that "knows" the variant, and hence it's price, so the only challenge is to find the old price on the button, and overwrite it. Simple stuff usually.

Comment: Hi David. I have spent hours on searching for similar problems, but I have not been able to find anything. Do you have an idea to fix this? The code from my product.liquid is here: https://www.paste.org/111482